# Get the sum of Total Churn_MTD(Current+2015+<2015)

Tags: sql-server-2012, stored-procedures, oracle-sql-developer

[image: **enter image description here**]
**how to declare 8 variables and get the total Sum,as you can see from the picture i created the 3 store procedures but dont know how to do the rest(Churn_MTD_Current_Year+Churn_MTD_Previous_Year+Churn_MTD_Less_Than_Previous_Year) then add it to (goal 2016+2015+less than 2015) then create temp table and store it there!!!!**